# How to make in tree node variable global

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

I want nodeid variable global

```
  $('.tree-title').tree({
       onClick: function (node) {
       var nodeid = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
       alert(nodeid);
     }
  });
```

i've tried put this code in function and make that function global so i can access but failed, then i do window.nodeid result is undefined

Comment: _"Why"_? I reckon you are doing something wrong :(

Comment: @rayon what do you mean wrong?

Comment: You did not answer my question :(

Comment: i am getting correct alert box, nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: __Why__ do you want it to be global ?

Comment: because i want that variable use in .. 
        var sOut = this.nodeid + ' <span class="form-required">*</span>';
        $("#lbl-name").html(sOut);
here

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do something like that but here we go:

```
$('.tree-title').tree({
  onClick: function(node) {
    window.myNodeId = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
    alert(window.MyNodeId);
  }
});
```

then you can access to `window.myNodeId` anywhere.

Comment: if i alert MyNodeId outside, its saying undefined

Comment: @rayon can you help me please sir.

Comment: after clicking at .tree-title ? be aware case sensitive MyNodeId != myNodeId

Comment: @AmolDavkhar, Can you share a fiddle

Comment: i have upload my code to the fiddle, fiddle name : Tree Hirarchy